# Registering a new FTS tokenizer in SQLite3 w/ Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm building an application which requires a custom Tokenizer in its FTS database. I have found a Tokenizer which does what I want ([this one](https://github.com/haifengkao/SqliteSubstringSearch)), but I can't find any directions for registering and using custom Tokenizers with the SQLite in Python.

Anyone have an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: This is not supported in Python (not even by APSW).

Comment: Not at all? That's a little disappointing. I'll probably have to go back to the drawing board on this app then.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to write your tokenizer in python, you could use [sqlitefts](https://pypi.org/project/sqlitefts/).

Here's an example tokenizer from the README:

```py
import sqlitefts as fts

class SimpleTokenizer(fts.Tokenizer):
    _p = re.compile(r'\w+', re.UNICODE)

    def tokenize(self, text):
        for m in self._p.finditer(text):
            s, e = m.span()
            t = text[s:e]
            l = len(t.encode('utf-8'))
            p = len(text[:s].encode('utf-8'))
            yield t, p, p + l

tk = sqlitefts.make_tokenizer_module(SimpleTokenizer())
fts.register_tokenizer(conn, 'simple_tokenizer', tk)
```